# Undefined value for TextArea in Lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, summer-16

I have a lightning component that contains a textarea.  There is an oninput event that fires on the textarea so I can inspect the value as it changes.

```
<textarea aura:id="my-textarea" placeholder="Comment here..." oninput="{!c.handleTextArea}"></textarea>
```

In the controller, I want to inspect the value of the textarea.  The value property should contain the text that's in the textarea.

```
handleTextArea : function(component, event, helper) {
  // this doesn't work, the value is always undefined
  var text = event.target.value;
  console.log(text);

  // this way doesn't work either, the value is undefined
  text = component.find("my-textarea").getElement().value;
  console.log(text);
}
```

**This issue started after the Summer '16 update in our org.**  Prior to the upgrade this was working fine.

Interestingly, if I change the `<textarea>` tag to an `<input>` then the value is available as expected.

Is this a bug?  Or am I missing something obvious here?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Interestingly, I created a dummy component to test your issue and both methods you used to retrieve the value of the textarea worked in my component. Note: the org I tested in is on Summer '16

Comment: The difference is likely that in one org Locker Service is activated and the other it is not.

Answer (score 3):

I suspect that this is a bug in LockerService (the .value attribute not being properly exposed in the secure virtual DOM). Have you opened a case with Salesforce support on this yet?

Comment: Hi Doug, thanks for the response. I have not opened a case yet, but I will.